# passing argument from one function to request.on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse

i am newbie to nodejs/javascript and trying to pass a value from a function.

Below is my request.on function ( i need to get favoriteStn value and pass it on while building the JSON array)

```
  response.on('end', function () {
             str = JSON.parse(str);
        var summariesJSON = str[0].summaries
          var resToSend = [];

            for(var i in summariesJSON) {

                var item = summariesJSON[i];
                var favoriteStn = findifFavorite (usernameFrmQuery,item.device_id,function(value){
                        favoriteStn = value;

                    });
                    resToSend.push({ 
                    "lat" : item.lat,
                    "lng"  : item.ln,
                    "count"       : item.count,
                    "status" : item.status,
                    "id" :   item.id,
                    "name"  :   item.name,
                    "address"   :   item.address,
                    "favoriteStn" : favoriteStn,
                    "fav_count" : findFavCount
                });
            } 
    res.send(resToSend);
  });


function findifFavorite (username,stationId,cb) {
    var options = {
    };
            ddb.getItem(chgStationfavorite, username, String(stationId), options, function(err, getitemRes, cap) {
            if (err) {
                cb("Failure" + err);
                } else if(typeof(getitemRes) != 'undefined'){

                cb("Y");
            }
                else {

                cb("N");
                }

        });

}
```

issue is i dont get anything created for favoriteStn, i know it is getting into the function and providing values as i can see it thru console.log

can you help me on how i need to use callback and get it working?

Comment: There is the async module that can come in handy when dealing with asynchronous functions https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Raj is right: you can do this with the async module. More specifically, replace the for loop with `async.map(summariesJSON, findIfFavorite, send)`. Then rewrite `findIfFavorite` so that it takes 2 arguments: `(item, cb)`, and replace `username` with `usernameFrmQuery`. (I don't see any declaration of `usernameFrmQuery` - you may need to move the definition of `findIfFavorite` so that `usernameFrmQuery` is in scope.) And replace `cb("N");` with `cb(null, { "lat": item.lat, ... });`. Then `function send(err, resToSend) { if(err) { ... } else { res.send(resToSend); } }`.

Comment: bit lost, where do i push to resToSend object the values?

Answer (score 0):

you have to consider everything in node.js is asynchronous.

in your case `findifFavorite` execution time is taking more time and the value is not available for the array.

this is how you can fix your code, you have to move the `resToSend` array in the callback function.

Start reading more about promises 
https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird
so you will not get stuck in callback hell.

```
                var favoriteStn = findifFavorite (usernameFrmQuery,item.device_id,function(value){
                    favoriteStn = value;

                        resToSend.push({ 
                           "lat" : item.lat,
                            "lng"  : item.ln,
                           "count"       : item.count,
                           "status" : item.status,
                           "id" :   item.id,
                           "name"  :   item.name,
                           "address"   :   item.address,
                           "favoriteStn" : favoriteStn,
                           "fav_count" : findFavCount
                         });

                        res.send(resToSend);


                });
```

Comment: thank you mahdi, but if i add res.send inside that, the issue is it will get inside a for loop and will have multiple res.send being sent isnt it

Comment: yeah valid point, just add if statement and only call the res.send when you are looping in the last element, make sure to pass  a boolean true/false to detect wether it's in the end of the loop or not.  `findifFavorite`, if you want to clean up your code you can use bluebird.  https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise